# Asus 1000HE Wireless Issues

Tags: 10.10, wireless, eeepc, ralink

A fresh install of 10.10 on my Asus 1000HE has caused some wireless issues.

At home, I have no issues with the wireless from my Linksys WRT54G router with WPA2 security.

On campus at my university, my netbook constantly connects to and disconnects from the unsecured wireless (that you must provide credentials to access).  Sometimes, if I'm lucky, it will stay connected for 5 minutes and I can check my email before it kicks off again.

This was not an issue before 10.10.  I believe I was running a proprietary Broadcom driver in previous releases of Ubuntu, but under "Additional Drivers" I no longer find any options for drivers.

Any help?

Please let me know if there's more information that would be helpful (and how I could go about retrieving it).

Thank you.

**EDIT:**  Relevant hardware information from `sudo lspci --`

```
00:1e.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge [8086:2448] (rev e2)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation 82801GBM (ICH7-M) LPC Interface Bridge [8086:27b9] (rev 02)
00:1f.1 IDE interface [0101]: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) IDE Controller [8086:27df] (rev 02)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 82801GBM/GHM (ICH7 Family) SATA AHCI Controller [8086:27c5] (rev 02)
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: RaLink RT2860 [1814:0781]
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Atheros Communications AR8121/AR8113/AR8114 Gigabit or Fast Ethernet [1969:1026] (rev b0)
```

Comment: Please add some hardware information to your question so we can begin, here are instructions: http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a well know issue, you can read [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EeePC/Fixes) in the topic **Ralink Card**

- Indicates trouble connecting to (some) wireless-n networks out of the box
- connection instability
- doesn't connect to 802.1x network

***Drivers***

Some threads have reported success using newer or older drivers from the ralink website (as of writing at 2.4.0.0 compared to the 1.8.0.0 version in the Ubuntu/Debian repository).

A method of installing a new driver is [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1476007).

Comment: This has seemingly worked a miracle; thank you.